# isNaN validation always returns TRUE but in browser it is FALSE

Tags: javascript, validation

so I am doing a function which supposed to make a block of 10 numbers, but in case if it is a string, prompt "can't be string" with window.alert.

So I am making a test with console.log to check if the value isNaN or not. It always returns true, but if I am doing the same thing in browser it is false, this is what makes me struggling. Kindly thank you for sharing your wisdom with me !

I was looking for the answer without success. Best regards.

```
btnCheck.addEventListener("click", divFunction);

function divFunction(){
  var number = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
  console.log(isNaN(number.value)); //Why it always print true ? 
if(isNaN(number.value) === "true"){window.alert("CAN'T BE STRING")}else{
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="";
  var i;
  for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML+=number+"</br>";
  }
 }
}


<input type="text" id="number" placeholder="give me number"></input>
    </br>
      <button id="buttonCheck">Cyc</button>
    </br>
      <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Because you set `number` to the input's value (not the element) and then try to get `.value` from it. Since `number` is already a number, it doesn't have a property `value`.

Comment: Numbers do not have a `.value` property - just use `isNaN(number)`. Also, `isNaN` always returns `true` or `false`, not a string value. So `isNaN(something) === 'true'` will always be false.

Comment: Dear Friends, I removed ".value" from ` if(isNaN(number.value) === "true" `
But unfortunately my function still prints numbers, or NaNs without prompting error.

Comment: ＠JLRishe　さん　誠にありがとうございます。お世話になっております。よろしく

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `.value` part. Do this instead:

```js
isNaN(number)
```

Comment: Dear Francis, it's still the same. So console.log prints now correctly, but function doesn't prompt an error

Comment: As @JLRishe mentionned, you also need to remove the `=== 'true` part as well. So your if statement should be `if (isNaN(number)) {`

Comment: It works, thank you very very much, tho I still don't understand it :-)